# How do PC monitor integrated menus work?

Tags: display, external-display

Your PC monitor usually has a menu button which allows you to directly control the monitors configuration like sharpness, aspect, volume, etc..

On mine there is an 'overlay' menu when you press the button. How does this happen? Is there a component that integrates the menu with the video-in signal? Is this firmware, or a driver? Could you 'hack' this to change the display? Could the display be controlled with variables rather than static data. E.g. driven from an application installed on the computer to create some neat overlay effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer needs a longer introduction.

Most computer-related things have modular structure. You think what's your problem, split it into easier problems and solve them, then you connect those partial solutions and you have one big solution. Actually this scheme applies not only to computers, you're probably using it everyday. (think about it: your activities consist of less complicated activities, for example to eat something you have to grab it, bite it and chew)

Monitors are modular too. It would be hard to work on one big piece of electronics. As it gets more and more complicated, you'd get mixed up. Creating smaller modules is easier. Replacing faulty modules is cheaper than replacing entire monitor.

So look at your monitor as a modular device. It has power supply module, display module and external input module.

Power supply is connected to every other module, because of course nothing would work without power. That's its job, it's just providing correct currents to correct modules.

Then the display. The display module itself doesn't care what it's showing. It's just a LCD panel and some electronics that translate input signal to pixels on that panel. It doesn't really matter what's on the display, only important thing for that module is if it understands the input signal.

That input signal comes from the external input module. Your monitor probably has few inputs (like VGA, DVI, HDMI or DisplayPort). Not all of these work the same way and none of these could directly control the display module. Connectivity module is here to translate those signals and send them to the display.

And that's basically a working monitor.

Now, display module can probably be controlled to change brightness, contrast, color temperature and so on. The connection between display and input modules can be intercepted to modify the signal. So we just add another module that sits between those two, has some buttons connected and does what we need.

Monitor's OSD isn't driver controlled. Main reason for this is that it's not only computers that work with monitors. You can connect anything and the OSD must still be there. It's provided by firmware.

About "hacking" monitors. You can do it in many ways, even without opening your monitor. Just connect some device between PC and monitor and program it to manipulate the screen. Again, monitor doesn't care what it's displaying, it's just a signal or a bunch of pixels (depending where you try to look at it).

It's all about manipulating the signals, that's what computers do by the definition.

Answer (score 4):

They're done entirely on the monitor - you can verify this by using them with the PC turned off. It will indeed be done as an overlay, and in theory you could probably hack the microprocessor on the monitor that generates them.

But if you want to change the display from a PC, it's *far* easier to do it on the PC, either in the drivers or through the operating system's accessibility overlay system.